# How to successfully transcribe audio files using Whisper for OpenAI in Python?

Tags: python, path, openai-api, transcription, openai-whisper

I´m trying to use Whisper model but occours an error saying:

UserWarning: FP16 is not supported on CPU; using FP32 instead
warnings.warn("FP16 is not supported on CPU; using FP32 instead")
file not found.
exiting process.

my code:

```
import whisper
import os

# created this logic to get the real path to the file

current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
file_name = "audio.wav"
file_path = os.path.join(current_dir, file_name)
print(file_path)

# the transcript logic:

listen = file_path

def transcribe():
    model = whisper.load_model("large")
    result = model.transcribe(listen)
    print(result["text"])
    return result

try:
    result = transcribe()
    with open("transcript.txt", "w") as file:
        file.write(result["text"])
    print("file saved")
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("file not found.")
except PermissionError:
    print("Not permitted to save file.")
except Exception as e:
    print("An unknow error occured:", str(e))
finally:
    print("exiting process.")
```

Thanks for now

By the way, I tried this:

```
current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
file_name = "audio.wav"
file_path = os.path.join(current_dir, file_name)
print(file_path)
```

and the path by itself = "C:\Users\rene.pessoto\Desktop\Audio\audio.wav" and
("C:\Users\rene.pessoto\Desktop\Audio", "audio.wav") but I can´t finish it yet.

*the file has 39 minutes and its size is 214MB

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using

`result = model.transcribe(listen)`

try to use this

```
options = whisper.DecodingOptions(fp16 = False)
result = whisper.decode(model, mel, options)
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the documentation/API may have changed since you posted this. The docs now say `File uploads are currently limited to 25 MB`, which could be an issue for you. The recommendation in the docs is to use `openai` and `open` before passing the file to the API, as such:

```
import openai
audio_file= open("/path/to/file/audio.mp3", "rb")
transcript = openai.Audio.transcribe("whisper-1", audio_file)
```

They also [recommend using `AudioSegment`](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/speech-to-text/longer-inputs) to break up the audio file in pieces.